# Count Reoccuring Values in Column of Google Spreadsheet Using Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, countif

I'd like to count the number of times a value reoccurs in a specific column of my spreadsheet using a script so that it populates a different column (same row) with the count when a form is submitted.  These are the values in Column B that I'd like to count:

6 ACM
5 ACM
4 ACM
5 CGC
7 CGC
6 ACM 
7 ACM
7 ACM

so that if the calculation were working correctly Column C would be populated with these numbers:

1
1
 
1
 
1
 
1
 
2
 
1
 
2

I know how to read the data and how to write to the spreadsheet, but I don't know how to actually count the values.  Here is what I have so far:

```
function countif() {
   var ss = null;
  try {
    ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0AliYViHYAwaNdHQyMXlKT2Q5UElQY184T3BWYTRiM2c");
  } catch (ex) {
    ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  }
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var lastLine = sheet.getLastRow();
  var data = sheet.getRange("B2:B").getValues();
  var count = 0;

//need help here

  sheet.getRange(lastLine,3).setValue(count);
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Put this piece of code in your //need help section.

```
for (var i = 0 ; i < lastLine ; i++){
  var count = 1;
  for ( var j = 0 ; j < i ; i ++) {
    if (data[j][0] == data[i][0] ){
      count++;
    }
  }
  sheet.getRange('C' + (i+1).toString()).setValue(count);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  This code gives me an error: "Argument must be a range" in reference to this line:

    sheet.getRange('C' + i.toString()).setValue(count);

Comment: Try the modified code. I think the problem was the first iteration would try and write to C0 which, of course, doesn't exist !

Comment: Hhhhmmm... now I'm getting: TypeError: Cannot read property "0" from undefined. Regarding this line

if (data[j][0] == data[i][0] ){

Comment: Try `var data = sheet.getRange("B2:B"+lastLine).getValues();`

Answer (score 0):

Just as an alternative, you can achieve this with a spreadsheet function, entered in C1:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(ROW(B:B)=1;"Count";IF(LEN(B:B);MMULT((ROW(B:B)>=TRANSPOSE(ROW(B:B)))*(B:B=TRANSPOSE(B:B));SIGN(ROW(B:B)));IFERROR(1/0))))
```

Comment: Thanks so much Adam.  I ended up using functions to make the entire sheet work properly and this function made it possible.  :)